# No signal error reappears once in a week

Tags: motherboard, hdmi, vga, lg-monitor

Built this PC 3 years ago and never faced any major issue. Recently I kept getting this no signal entering safe mode errors. The issue will disappear once I reset cmos but reappear after a week. I kept doing this for 3 weeks but now I want permanent solution.
Issue is same with HDMI+gpu , HDMI+ Mobo , vga + Mobo. 
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried another monitor?

Comment: Yes. Same issue.